# Get generic type of a property based on enum/type of another property

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript, can I have an interface where one property is a enum/type and another property is a certain type based on the first property?
I guess an example will explain it better:

```js
interface MyFruitModel {
  id: number;
  fruitType: Apple | Orange | Banana;
  result: AppleResult | OrangeResult | BananaResult;
}

const banana: MyFruitModel = {
  id: 0,
  fruitType: Banana
  result: {
    // Typescript should know, that this is BananaResult
  }
}
```

This is an example with union types. I could also declare enums if it makes a difference.
Is this possible with generics?

Comment: Why not use a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions)?

Comment: VLAZ is correct: you would need to make a union of BananaModel | AppleModel | OrangeModel with the appropriate fruitType and result matchings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to group the result type (BananaResult) with its initial type (Banana). One approach is to have a dictionary where the keys are just some unique string related to the type and the values is an object with properties `fruitType` and `result`:

```
type TypeMap = {
  banana: { fruitType: Banana; result: BananaResult };
  orange: { fruitType: Orange; result: OrangeResult };
  apple: { fruitType: Apple; result: AppleResult };
};
```

Then, we need to use [discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) to ensure that the result and type are related. In our case we can simply get a *union* of all values from the `TypeMap` using the [indexed access](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html):

```
// {
//     fruitType: Banana;
//     result: BananaResult;
// } | {
//     fruitType: Orange;
//     result: OrangeResult;
// } | {
//     fruitType: Apple;
//     result: AppleResult;
// }
type Test = TypeMap[keyof TypeMap];
```

Looks good! Now, let's *intersect* the common field in the type (`id`) with this union:

```
type MyFruitModel = { id: number } & TypeMap[keyof TypeMap];
```

Testing:

```
const banana: MyFruitModel = { // no error
  id: 0,
  fruitType: { banana: '' },
  result: {
    bananaResult: '',
  },
};

const bananaIncorrect: MyFruitModel = { // error
  id: 0,
  fruitType: { banana: '' },
  result: {
    orangeResult: '',
  },
};
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgO0XKBeKBvKAjZSBcUA5EVAL4DcAUKJFAPIBOiA5tOlgPbMJuEnlqtaAEEwYADbtMUOOKn9SlKjXDR4SJACUIAZwCuE4Ghm5NcHQaOLBquk1YRLh4xyjdHz68SVC1UMUknPRcTLDkgr2AbZTtoABU1AFk5MKooHDw4QiwAM0Z9AEtgRMhCDWQKKEYQ7wrtWuNlDI9eCByofKKStUIHNqqaq2iGHjYo2wyIhRku4tL2gPkIQcbCQKkJ5VjhKCSQADEC4qTOABMICTCoQrPCBH0AW2wIRnIoADIoBZSwAG0ANYQECcXLfZJyAC61CoAGNOAhdMYzMhCPsjt1Thcrhx0jc7lAAAwAGjxcx6ZVMWRipIyQxcOTxGRRDWGilp5FJsXhiORWQAkgh4YwarCRujjsAsZc0hlboQSWTJQsOizsj5OXj6d4MEz3GNgmyfByyFzqEA)